# Ideas/Suggestions implementing some OpenID authentication use-case involving android app and NFC

Tags: android, authentication, openid-connect, nfc, openid

I am working on a project where we want to integrate some additional authentication mechanism that involves mobile devices and NFC tags. As a simplification for explaining the problem, one could imagine some kind of user checkin/checkout feature.

**Outline/Vision:**

- administrators of the application can assign NFC tags to existing users in our system, one NFC tag can only be assigned to a single user
- there will be multiple permanently mounted android devices with our app installed
- the android app reacts to NFC tags near the device and sends a checkin/checkout request to our backend
- optimally the app should use our existing REST API, which we are using from our web application already (in the context of a logged in user)
- checkin/checkout (on the backend) should take place in the context of the user represented by the NFC tag
- the android app will handle checkin/checkout from multiple users (NFC tags)

**Unclear points:**

- how will the android app "connect" itself to our backend (UX as simple as possible)?
- how can the existing REST API be called in the context of the user represented by the NFC tag?

In general we want to prefer the usage of standard protocols like OpenID connect and reduce custom/proprietary authentication code to a minimum. As the IDP implementation for our regular user login we are currently using Keycloak.

**Do you guys have any pointers or suggestions on how to implement the authentication for such a use-case?**

Answer (score 0):

This may not provide you with a working solution, but is meant to describe how the building blocks of OAuth might be used.

Feels like the desired behaviour is a custom native authentication method to identify users, then to call a backend with an access token. This is a tricky problem and not too well supported in OAuth. Solution ingredients might look like this:

- Client (your mobile app) triggers an OpenID Connect flow to authenticate users at a suitable point. This may or may not present a screen to the user.
- The most common way to do OAuth for mobile is described in [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252) and involves opening the system browser. The authorization server could then invoke a configured custom authentication method for the client.
- The browser would then need to do the scanning of NFC tags
- Once complete the app gets an access token and can call APIs.

**POSSIBLE FUTURE OPTIONS FOR NATIVE OAUTH?**

Yet the system browser may not be above to deal with NFC tags, in which case it prevents the above flow from working. A better option might be to implement the OIDC flow like this:

- Client triggers an OIDC flow by sending API requests to the authorization server, rather than using the system browser.
- Client  gets an API response that tells it to begin its native authentication.
- Client does the scanning using native code, which might include the use of a native SDK that does NFC tag scanning
- Client POSTs NFC tag data to the authorization server to verify. This would require some kind of `plugin` to implement the custom logic based on backend user associations.
- Doing this work in the context of an OIDC flow would enable the app to get an OAuth 2.0 token afterwards.

At Curity, where I work, we have been investing in something called the `Hypermedia Authentication API`, which provides better support for native authentication use cases within an OAuth context. My answer is meant to describe a design pattern rather than any particular implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

As @gary-archer mentions, OAuth 2.0 is the standard protocol to access secured APIs. If you are using Keycloak you probably already have OAuth 2.0 in place, which is good. Now, I don't know what "regular user login" implies, but commonly, when running OAuth 2.0/OIDC with apps, the flow passes the browser. So, what you need is a way for Keycloak to read the NFC tag via the browser. But since the app and IdP belong to the same party, you may want to remove the browser from the flow and implement an API-driven approach as provided by the `Hypermedia Authentication API` from Curity which is actually similar to what is described in the `OAuth 2.0 for First-Party Native Applications`: https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-parecki-oauth-first-party-native-apps-00.html.
The API-driven approach is not yet standardized and probably requires major updates in Keycloak as it introduces a new protocol and endpoints. So, if you want to go down that road, you may want to consider another IdP.